# SwiftUI draw a file icon

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, drawing

I would like to be able to get an image like this, with the word "File" in the center.

[image]

But I only managed to do this, you know how to give me a hand.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics

struct File: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let topsx = CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.minY)
        let topdx = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX/1.5, y: 0)
        let bottomsx = CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.maxY)
        let bottomdx = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: bottomdx)
        path.addLine(to: bottomdx)
        path.addLine(to: bottomsx)
        path.addLine(to: topsx)
        path.addLine(to: topdx)
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            File().fill(Color.black)
            Text("File")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not try to draw the icon with code.

Here's a simplified solution with a SF Symbol, but you can just find a nice document icon, download it, add it to your assets and use that instead.

```
 ZStack {
        Image(systemName: "doc.fill").resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .overlay {
                Text("File").font(.title).foregroundColor(.white).shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 5, y: 5).offset(x:0, y: 20)
        }
    }.frame(height:200)
```

[image: Sample Image]